# Data passing with Laravel 5.0 and select 2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, jquery-select2

Following tutorials on laravel 5 fundamentals, I am studying laravel 5.0.
I am adding an original feature to the blog project shown on the tutorials.

I would like to go to the page that edits the article that I select by putting the id of the article to url.
However, I don't know what I am supposed to do.
Has anyone dealt with a similar problem before?

```
        $('#title').select2({
            placeholder: 'choose an article',
            maximumSelectionLength: 1,
            tag: true
        });


        $('#article-form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var title = $('#title').val();
            $(this).attr('action', 'articles/'+ title).submit();
        }); 
    });
</script>


<h1>Articles</h1>
 {!! Form::model($article, ['method' => 'GET', 'id' => 'article-form', 'url' => 'articles/'.$article->id]) !!}

<div class = "form-group">
    {!! Form:: label('title', 'Title: ') !!}
    {!! Form:: select('title[]', $title, null, ['id' => 'title', 'class' => 'form-control', 'multiple']) !!}
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">show the content</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}

<hr/>
```

This is my route

```
 Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

[image: Display error]

Comment: Try this: `Form:: select('title'`

Comment: Thank you very much for improving the format of my question, Manix!

Comment: I have already tried that, but now I have difficulty dealing with one of jquery errors, which is Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: When you are working with javascript/jQuery or developing websites is very useful that you install some extensions in your current browser in order to know about the errors behind the scenes. For example, in firefox developer edition you can see errors in console log that helps to debug problems like this. In firefox and chrome there is a tool named firebug. Open your website using these tools and paste the console errors in the question ;)

Comment: I have no idea, but once I deleted e.preventDefault();, it works the way I want it to. Problem solved! Thank you very much for helping me out, Manix!

Comment: Great! you are welcome